# How to query and filter soft-deleted Eloquent models in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading, soft-delete

Using Laravel 4.1 starter kit from https://github.com/snipe/laravel4-starter, I have 2 models: Categories and Interests. Both also are soft-deletable. I would like the index View to display 3 different lists depending on the users wish: "Show all", "Show deleted" and "Show non-deleted".
All was fine until I added a HasMany/BelongsTo relationship between them.

*MODELS:*

```
class Category extends Elegant
{
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function interests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Interest');
    }
}

class Interest extends Elegant
{
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

Now when the view calls `$interest->category->name` on an Interest that belongs to a soft-deleted Category, it all blows up with `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object`. I suspect that this is because the `$interest->category` is NULL as it did not get loaded since it has been soft-deleted.

*CONTROLLER:*

```
class InterestsController extends AdminController
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $showDisabled = Utility::GetShowDisabled();

        switch ($showDisabled) {
            case 'only':
                // How to load *only* soft-deleted Interest with their categories
                // even if the category has been soft-deleted?
                $interests = Interest::onlyTrashed()->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
                break;
            case 'with':
                // How to load *all* Interests with their categories
                // even if the category has been soft-deleted?
                $interests = Interest::withTrashed()->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
                break;

            default:
                // How to load *only* *NON-soft-delted* Interests with their categories
                // even if the category has been soft-deleted?
                $interests = Interest::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
                break;
        }

        return View::make('backend/interests/index', compact('interests', 'showDisabled'));
    }
```

See my questions in each 3 sections of the switch statement. I suspect that the solution will involved some sort of eager loading, but even after some pretty intense Googling and experimentation the correct incantation still eludes me....

EXTRA POINTS: How would one load all Interests that are *NON-soft-deleted* while filtering out Interests that have soft-deleted categories?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eager load category:

```
Interest::with(['category' => function ($q) {
   $q->withTrashed();
}])->onlyTrashed()->get();
// the same for other cases
```

interests that have category (non-deleted):

```
Interest::with('category')->has('category')->get();
```

Comment: You get the extra points the second part of your answer works. Unfortunately the main part of my problem remains. `$interests = Interest::with('category')->onlyTrashed()->get();` Loads all interests that are deleted, and pre-load their categories. The problem is that it only pre-loads non deleted categories. So the view still breaks. I would want to load the interests and preload the categories even if those categories are deleted. Here the `onlyTrashed()` is applied to the Interest part of the query.

Comment: Then rephrase your question, for it's not what you asked for. Anyway, check the edit for how to apply anything on the eager loading query. Mind that you can still have `interest` that has no `category` related (no matter deleted or not), so basically you want to check for `null` on that relation anyway..

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, how would you have phrased the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jarek Tkaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/jarek-tkaczyk) for the tip.
For a complete reference to others here is the bit of code that I ended up using:

```
    $query = Interest::with(array('category' => function ($subQuery) {
        $subQuery->withTrashed();
    }));

    switch ($showDisabled) {
        case 'only':
            $query->onlyTrashed();
            break;
        case 'with':
            $query->withTrashed();
            break;
        case 'without':
            break;

        default:
            $showDisabled = "activeonly";
            $query->has('category');
            break;
    }

    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $searchQ);
    $query->where( function ($subQuery) use ($searchTerms) {
        $termCnt = 0;
        foreach($searchTerms as $term)
        {
            (0 == $termCnt)
                ? $subQuery->Where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
                : $subQuery->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
            $termCnt++;
        }
    });

    $interests = $query->orderBy($sortByCol, $order)->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
SoftDeleted = true;
```

use:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

This work's fine for me.